# An enumeration in the .NET Framework class library that represents the programming languages supported?

Tags: .net

Short question: exists an enumeration within the .NET Framework class library that represents the programming languages supported by the .NET platform? (such as C#, VB.NET and F#)?

I'm aware of the [EnvDTE.CodeModelLanguageConstants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.codemodellanguageconstants?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) and [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.languagenames?view=roslyn-dotnet) classes which exposes public string fields. I would like to find something similar but expressed as a enumeration, and within the built-in namespaces of the .NET Framework class library as long as possible.

So I'm looking for a built-in enum member that could return me something similar to this:

```
public enum NetLanguage : int {
    CSharp,
    FSharp,
    VisualBasicNet,
    VisualC
}
```

Notes:

- Only CSharp and VBNet values are really required to me in such hypothetical enum.
- Mapping the string constants from any of those classes to a custom enum is not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1):

- [EnvDTE.CodeModelLanguageConstants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.codemodellanguageconstants?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) represents the languages that VS itself, the IDE, understands in terms of Intellisense support and syntax highlighting.
- [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.languagenames?view=roslyn-dotnet) are the languages that the Roslyn compiler understands, and that's exactly three: C#, VB and F#.

What you want doesn't even make sense, because anyone can (and people do) write their own language that use the .Net Framework. It's not what the .Net Framework supports, it's what compilers support the .Net Framework.

Comment: "What you want doesn't even make sense", I just would like to know if exists a Enum with values that at least represents VB.NET and C# languages. I even wrote a example of such hypothetical enum in my main post. Of course it makes sense. What does not make sense is writing a answer to talk about developing own languages. My question was clear, I don't deserve phrases like "What you want doesn't even make sense". Thanks anyway.

Comment: It always baffles me why people who seem to think they know better even bother asking questions on this site, getting a response, then disregarding it because, again, they know better. You're just going to get your question closed as nonsense anyway, because that's what it is.

Comment: The only difference between asking whether the .NET framework class library expose a built-in member to trim and string, and what I've asked, is that the first thing is very easy to find on Google, articles, examples, or just by learning the basic usage, however, on the other hand what I've asked it is more uncertain or "obscure", but essentially it is the same kind of question, and it does not deserve answers that dismiss the question only to claim without foundation that the question "it makes no sense".